# Can react-snapshot map out the paths as S3 requires?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I'm new to React and built a simple app that displays two pages:

```
Home for /
Team for /team
```

I'm decent with AWS, so the static build over there with CloudFront needs a path like `/team/index.html` to render my Team page.

Found out about react-snapshot which generates the .html pages but adds them to the react root directory as `/team.html` whereas I would need it to be `/team/index.html` in the S3 bucket.

Sure, I can rename it manually, create a folder with the proper naming as S3 requires and add it to the folder, however..

My question is, assuming you'd have 50 of these pages `/team /about /etc`, do you know a better way to deploy to S3 in order to match the required path?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like what you actually want is just not a single-page app.

Comment: That's correct. I'm building a simple presentation site in React with several pages.